# Want to create DNS Server on two Machine with One Domain

Tags: linux

I Want to create DNS Server in two different Machines but with same domain
It is Possible to create DNS with sub Domain of Main Domain

Like in  1st machine use simran.com and in 2nd Machine use Sim.simran.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible.

It's the same thing as having `.com` and `simran.com` nameservers on different systems. The `.com` nameservers have `NS` resource records for `simran.com` that point to the right nameservers (the IP addresses of those nameservers).

Similarly your 1st machine needs to have a `NS` record for `sim.simran.com` with the IP address of your 2nd machine.